# Are Axiomatic systems derived from Law?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, history-of-philosophy

Axiomatic systems arose in Greece & India in Geometry and Language, the exemplary texts being Euclids *Elements* and  Paninis *Ashtadyayi* (grammar).

Now, when one considers the idea of [Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law#History_of_law):

> Law is a term which does not have a universally accepted definition, but one definition is that law is a system of rules and guidelines which are enforced through social institutions to govern behavior.

When, one considers that Law as an idea must predates the invention of axiomatic systems by millenia, and that (at least to me) there is a clear correspondance of between the idea of Law and Axiomatic Systems. Whereas in the former, it is human beings who are subject to law, and in the latter it is the behaviour of (at least in Euclid) points & lines that are governed not through social institutions (at least directly) but through the individual intellect.

One also thinks of 'the law of large numbers' and 'law of gravitation' where it appears this idea in a primitive sense appears.

Has anyone explored this thesis?

Comment: I suggest you Reviel Netz , The Shaping of Deduction in Greek Mathematics: A Study in Cognitive History (Cambridge University Press - 2003).

Comment: See also G.E.R.Lloyd, Demystifying mentalities (Cambridge U.P. - 1990) : Ch.3. The conception and practice of
proof.